What are the performance impact on Amazon Aurora RDS PostgreSQL when using Redshift Federated Queries on it?
What are the performance considerations while using the Redshift Federated Queries to access and query data present in Amazon Aurora RDS PostgreSQL database? The Redshift Zero ETL feature is still in preview for PostgreSQL and hence exploring the feature of Redshift Federated Query.
Looking for recommendations around volume of data, number of tables, etc. that should be considered while using this feature.

Federated queries basically act the same as connecting to the instance in say dbeaver and running the select statements yourself… unless u are using them in joins and filtered queries, in which case it’ll apply the where clause to the query too. Anyways I mean it’s fine if u point it to a read replica of the rds, but still I prefer to not touch a prod db for etl under any circumstances. Until zeroetl (cough cough free dms) goes GA for Postgres, I’ve been doing rds snapshot exports to s3 and then accessing the data via spectrum.
